# How to evaluate an integral in a multiple connect region

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-fields, greens-theorem

a while ago I was faced by this problem:

> Let $D$ be a multiple connected region interior to $C$ and exterior to
> $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ (See figure). We know that $Q_{x} - P_{y} = 0$.
>
> 1. What is the value of $\oint_{C} F. dr$?
> 2. If $\oint_{C_{1}} P dx + Q dy = 2$ and $\oint_{C_{2}} P dx + Q dy = 3$, what is the value of $\oint_{C} P dx + Q dy$?

This is the region:

[image: Region D.]

**My attempt:**

Well, if $Q_{x} - P_{y} = 0$, then $F$ is conservative, so, $\oint_{C} F. dr = 0$.

For the second part, I don't know how to proceed, I was thinking in sum both of the $C_{i}$ integrals.

Can someone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ${\bf F} = \langle P,Q\rangle$, Green's theorem  (which remains true for multiply connected regions) gives
$$ \int_{\partial D} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} = \int_{\partial D}P\,dx+Q\,dy =\iint_D (Q_x-P_y)\,dx\,dy = 0.$$
With the given orientations, we have $\partial D = C+C_1+C_2$ (keep in mind the inner boundary orientations need to clockwise rather than counterclockwise, which we have in this case). Thus
$$ \int_{\partial D} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} = \oint_{C} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}+\oint_{C_1} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}+\oint_{C_2} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}.$$
It follows that
$$\oint_{C} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r} = -\oint_{C_1} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}-\oint_{C_2} {\bf F}\cdot d{\bf r}.$$
So there isn't a numerical answer to the first problem, since it depends on the value of the integrals along the inner boundaries. I imagine you thought ${\bf F}$ was conservative because $Q_x = P_y$ in $D$, but that implication only works in a simply-connected region (and $D$ is not). You would be able to conclude the integral around $C$ is $0$ if $Q_x = P_y$ everywhere inside $C$, but I don't think this is what they meant (since in this case, the situation of $2$ would be impossible; the integrals around the inner boundaries could not be nonzero numbers).

Anyway, for 2, the above formula implies
$$\oint_C P\,dx+Q\,dy = -2-3 = -5.$$

Comment: Yes, I thougt that $F$ was conservative, but I didn't pay the right attention to the non simple-connectedness of $D$. Great answer, btw!

Comment: How is problem #1 different from problem #2? Aren't problem #1 and problem #2 asking you to evaluate the same line integral?

Comment: I'm just guessing (it's not like I wrote the question), but I think they wanted you to derive a general formula in 1 and then apply that general formula in 2.

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean. The whole $Q_x-P_y$ bit is very misleading. The problem really should specify that the curl vanishes strictly in $D$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. (It also just occurred to me I had $R$s in a lot of places where I meant $D$, which should be fixed now).

Comment: I found this in a PDF from a teacher in my university.